# Remove Lines From Image Printed From Thermal Bluetooth Printer In Android

Tags: android, thermal-printer

I am printing an image in a receipt via a thermal bluetooth printer in an android app. The issue is that lines are showing through the image. How can i remove the lines? The image is embedded below

[image: Lines are displayed through the qrcode]

The code i use is shown below

```
    int lineWidth = 384;

    int size0NoEmphasizeLineWidth = 320 / 8; //line width / font width
    String singleLine = "";
    String singleLine2 = "";
    int size0NoEmphasizeLineWidth2 =200 / 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < size0NoEmphasizeLineWidth; ++i) {
        singleLine += "-";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size0NoEmphasizeLineWidth2; ++i) {
        singleLine2 += "-";
    }
    String doubleLine = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < size0NoEmphasizeLineWidth; ++i) {
        doubleLine += "=";
    }

    int id = R.drawable.qrcode;
    Bitmap logoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),id);
    int logoTargetWidth =150;
    byte[] d1 = convertBitmap(logoBitmap, logoTargetWidth, 150);


    try {
        OutputStream baos = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        baos.write(INIT);
        baos.write(POWER_ON);
        baos.write(NEW_LINE);
        baos.write(ALIGN_CENTER);
        baos.write(SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE);
        baos.write(PrinterCommandsAlgon.FEED_LINE);
        baos.write(SET_LINE_SPACING_30);

        for(int j = 0; j < d1.length / logoTargetWidth; ++j) {
         baos.write(hexToByteArray("1B2A00"));
         baos.write((byte)logoTargetWidth);
         baos.write((byte)(logoTargetWidth >> 8));
         byte[] temp = new byte[logoTargetWidth];
         System.arraycopy(d1, j * logoTargetWidth, temp, 0, temp.length);
         baos.write(temp);
         baos.write(NEW_LINE);
         }

        baos.write(NEW_LINE);
        baos.write(CHAR_SPACING_0);

        baos.write(FONT_SIZE_0);
       
          baos.write(NEW_LINE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the line spacing is set to 30 dots.

```
baos.write(SET_LINE_SPACING_30);
```

Please try changing the value you set to 24 dots or close to it.
If it's not the right height, try different values.