# Print Image ESC/POS

Tags: c#, xamarin, printing, escpos

I'm using [this](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET/) API to print images in my thermal printer with Bluetooth connection. I tested using this [image](https://logosmarcas.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Nike-Logo.png) that have 3840x2160 of resolution, and it prints perfectly. I drew a bitmap using SkiaSharp, save it on my device, but I'm trying to print it and I can't set the height.

I tried some resolutions:

1280x720

720x720

Even if my image have 3840 of width (e.g the example of the link), the function put the limit of 372, and it works, but not with height.

I can't control the height and it's cutting my bitmap and just printing not even the half of it.

My bitmap is a list, probably 372 of width and 800 of height.

Code:

```
            EPSON e = new EPSON();
            ConnectBluetooth("ThermalPrinter");
            var outStream = (OutputStreamInvoker)socket.OutputStream;
            string directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            string logoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "bmp.png");
            var logo = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(logoPath);

            byte[] buffer = null;

            buffer = ByteSplicer.Combine(
                e.PrintImage(logo, true, true, 372, 0)
            );
            await outStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            buffer = null;

            socket.Close();
            socket.Dispose();
```

On the `PrintImage` it goes to:

`byte[] PrintImage(byte[] image, bool isHiDPI, bool isLegacy = false, int maxWidth = -1, int color = 1)`

and I receive this `byte[]` and send to print. Link [here](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET/blob/b118b98ae6167dd3f8248333187287da460bcb2e/ESCPOS_NET/Emitters/BaseCommandEmitter/ImageCommands.cs#L110).

PS: I already change the parameters of `PrintImage` but it still printing a "logo size" image, not the whole image. If I reduce the font size of the text inside my bitmap, I see more text when i print it, so it could be the height of what it will print, not a problem on the bitmap (when I open it in the gallery of my device, is perfect).

Comment: what is the DPI of your image?  The Nike logo is 72 DPI

Comment: @Jason I don't know this information, it doesn't appeared to me. My image is 700 of width and 1280 of height, size of 81KB and 32 of bits intensivity. PNG format. Is there any way to see the DPI of the image to I help you to solve this problem?

Comment: look at the image properties with any image tool

Comment: Downloaded GIMP... Didn't notice. So, it's 72 DPI too.

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on their github

Comment: If there is a problem with the library or it lacks functionality, your application can pre-adjust the image to the size you want.

Comment: @kunif But my image size is correct. The problem is when I print it. I tested with Nike Logo and it works. I can print the whole bitmap on the space that the printing is giving to me, but will be soooo tiny.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if the image file size information is correct. Considering the current behavior of the library, it is better to adjust the contents of the image data before requesting printing to the library so that you can obtain the print result you want.

Comment: @kunif I understand your point. Imagine a logo: it has more width than height. I'm trying to print a list, and it prints a logo size, I can't adjust the "list" image for this size, it will be distorted/shrunk.

Comment: What is a "list" image? I can't imagine it. It will be easier to get advice and answers if you add an image of the actual print result and a graphic representation of the print result you want.

Comment: @kunif list image is more height than width. Nike logo that I tested is logo: more width than height. My list image is printing in a logo size. I'm not sure if I can post, it's work rules and this stuff. my bitmap is literally a list, but in a bitmap that I save in PNG format and send to printer.

Comment: So it's better to show the actual print result that you think is the problem, as in this article [Remove Lines From Image Printed From Thermal Bluetooth Printer In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67286918/9014308), rather than the text. Then you can create and add what the desired print result looks like by handwriting or with a tool.

Comment: @Jason and kunif, I opened an issue on github, this is the [link](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET/issues/111) if you want to follow the solution. Thanks for the help.